# Is it safe to downgrade Virtualbox from 4 to 3?

Tags: virtualbox, downgrade

A couple weeks ago, I upgraded from Virtualbox 3.2 to Virtualbox 4.  I've had nothing but problems with it, grr!

Is it safe to just uninstall Virtualbox 4, and reinstall Virtualbox 3.2?  Does VB4 change any of my settings or VMs or disk images to a format that VB3.2 will have trouble with?

In case it matters, I'm on a Windows Vista (64-bit, Ultimate) host with a Linux (Debian, amd64) guest.

Answer (score 1):

I had to go back to VirtualBox 3 and aside from reinstalling the older version of Guest Additions in my VMs, I didn't have any problems downgrading.